# Springboot MongoDB connection URI is specifed in other key (not using spring.data.mongodb.uri)

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

For my Springboot application, I have a requirement that MongoDB URI should be specified with "app1.mongodb.uri" in application.properties.  Yes we don't want to use "spring.data.mongodb.uri" because I was told that it's misleading (what!?).  Does anyone know what is the simplest way to do that ? My application is all running fine, and I'm so reluctant to make any big change because of this "requirement".

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out how to do it.  The trick is to override the beam MongoClient and Mongotemplate.

```
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class MongoDBConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration  {

  
  @Value("${app1.mongodb.db}")
  private String database;
  
  @Value("${app1.mongodb.uri}")
  private String uri;  
  
  @Override
  @Bean
  public MongoClient mongoClient() {
    MongoClientURI mongoURI  = new MongoClientURI(uri); 
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(mongoURI);
    return client;
  }

  @Override
  protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return database;
  }

  @Bean
  public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongoClient(), getDatabaseName());
  }
  
}
```